# How to remove 'Message log' tab from profile page?

Tags: privatemsg

I've got this tab on profile pages of all users and for whoever I've tested, pressing this tab just yields:

> No logged messages

So it seems a real glitch that comes with some module which I've no clue of. So just wondering how can I remove the tab?

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the Messages modules; it has nothing to do with Private messages.

It's not a glitch, it's what this module does: a simple example of a way to deliver messages (notifications) to users.

Comment: Dear Berdir, how can I remove the tab?

Comment: Disable the module? I think adding that tab is all it does. Should be called "Web messaging".

Comment: I could not find anything like 'Messages' module being installed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which module causing this, but this [Tab Tamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module is always helpful. You can hide any tabs with [Tab Tamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer).

> Tab Tamer is an administration utility that provides easy re-ordering, hiding, and deactivation of tabs and subtabs. You can also **rename** tab labels.

Comment: Thanks for the useful hint. I'll follow this approach in case I could not find the real culprit :)